# Как получить данные в PHP из массивов в FormData

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, formdata

не могу решить проблему:

Я создаю массивы с данными, в том числе с картинками, и добавляю их в FormData.

```
$('#confirmYes').on('click', function() {
            
            var mySubTasks = [];
                $('.subTasky').each(function(){
                  mySubTasks.push({
                    taskId: $(this).attr('id'),
                    taskTitle: $(this).children('.currentInput').val(),
                    taskComment: $(this).children().children('.currentInputCom').val(),
                    taskImg: $(this).children('.taskPhoto').prop("files")[0]
                  });
                });
                
            var myHeaders = [];
                $('.subHeader').each(function(){
                  myHeaders.push({
                      header: $(this).children('.listInput').val()
                  });
                });
                
            var mySubSub = [];
                $('.subsub').each(function(){
                  mySubSub.push({
                      subId: $(this).attr('id'),
                      subTitle: $(this).children('.currentInput').val(),
                      subComment: $(this).children().children('.currentInputCom').val()
                  });
                });
                
            var myPrime = [];
                $('#mainTaskBox').each(function(){
                  mySubSub.push({
                      mainTitle: $(this).children('.listPrTitle').val(),
                      mainComment: $(this).children().children('.listPrCom').val(),
                      mainImg: $(this).children().children('.taskPhoto').prop("files")[0]
                  });
                });
            
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('mySubTasks', JSON.stringify(mySubTasks));
            formData.append('myHeaders', JSON.stringify(myHeaders));
            formData.append('mySubSub', JSON.stringify(mySubSub));
            formData.append('myPrime', JSON.stringify(myPrime));
```

Затем отправляю эти данные через Ajax

```
$.ajax({
                        url: '../db/savelist.php',
                        method: 'POST',
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        cache: false,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: formData,
                        success:(function(data){
                            $('.loader').hide();
                            console.log(data);
                            if(data=='ok'){                 
                                alert('ok');
                                
                            }   
                            else {
                                
                            }
                        })  
                    });
```

Как мне получить данные из массива `myPrime` в PHP файле? Сейчас я пробую такой код, но он не работает.

```
$user = 'user@mail.ru';
$mainTask = json_decode($_POST['formData']);
if(isset($mainTask->mainTitle) == true) {
    
    
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'wtf';
}
```

Как мне получить данные из массивов в FormData, так чтобы можно было еще работать с файлами с input file?

Comment: в $_FILES заглядывал? и почему dataType: 'json' ?

Comment: так я ж передаю в FormData json значение - `formData.append('mySubTasks', JSON.stringify(mySubTasks));`

Comment: и что, джейсон картинку передаёт? вар-дамп почаще используй.

Comment: а разве нет? Если нет, то как тогда передать все это через ajax и вытащить в php?

Comment: вот тебе примеры https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно получать данные на php примерно так `$_POST['mySubTasks']`

Comment: Не, мне нужно получить данные `taskComment` из этого массива, а не сам массив.

Comment: Ну когда вы получили массив он должен содержать объекты и нужно сделать цикл по массиву для получение нужных данных 

foreach ($_POST['mySubTasks'] as $item) {
    echo $item['taskTitle'];
    echo $item['taskComment'];
}